# Change the structure automatically? (iOS/Storyboard)

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

To know better what I mean, check this screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cniuo.jpg). Let's say the UIView with the number 3 are removed. Is it possible to tell the storyboard or ViewController it should after the remove put the UIView number 4 and 5 higher (the y-position), so that it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X75wv.jpg) screenshot?

Sorry for the very basic question, but I have no idea how I could start or if this have a special name, to google it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This job is best fit for a vertical `UIStackView` , as setting

```
self.view3.isHidden = true
```

will automatically collapse the view , but if the items count will be many than fit in a single device height , then you have to embed the stackView inside a `UIScrollView` , or use a `UITableView` instead

Comment: That's awesome, thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity: Is it without a UIStackView also possible?

Comment: yes , but you need to manage the collapse yourself , by hooking the height constraint of the target view as outlet  and setting it's constant = 0